# For loop if - not matching string even though string exists

Tags: string, python-2.7, matching

The below code does not match in all the if statements.
I would like to know what makes the if statement match in the 2nd for loop, but not in the 1st and 3rd for loop?

```
for line in x:
    if '0.0.0.0/0' and 'A' in line:
        y = re.findall(r'\b\d{2,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', str(line))
```

These are the lines in x.
No lines get matched but correct value still goes into y because it is the only one which matches regex.
0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          41.222.225.255            0
1 ADC  41.222.225.255/32  197.242.206.100 pppoe-out1                0
2 ADC  172.20.0.0/24      172.20.0.1      LAN                       0

```
gw = []
for line in x:
        if y and '/32' in line:
        gw.append(str(line).split()[4])
```

Line in x which gets matched as expected.
I have not shown the other lines which do not get matched
 1 ADC  41.222.225.255/32  197.242.206.100 pppoe-out1                0

```
mtu = []
for line in x:
    print line
    if str(gw) in line:
        mtu.append(re.findall(r'actual-mtu=\d{1,4}\s*', str(x)))
```

Line in x which does not get matched.
13  R  name=pppoe-out1 type=pppoe-out mtu=1480 actual-mtu=1480 fast-path=yes last-link-down-time=jun/15/2017 20:37:43 last-link-up-time=jun/15/2017 20:37:44 link-downs=11

Comment: `'0.0.0.0/0' and 'A' in line` does not test if either value is in the line. `'A' in line` does, but boolean operators don't understand english grammar. `'0.0.0.0/0'` is tested separately, and always true because it is a non-empty string.

Comment: In this case, I'd use `if '0.0.0.0/0' in line and 'A' in line:`

Comment: Yes that worked for the 1st loop. Thank you